# Where am I going wrong in Dijkstra's implementation for shortest distance from source

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest distances of all vertices from the source vertex 1.

This is my implementation:

```
from ast import literal_eval


p = {}
with open(r'dijk.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
            line_content = line.split()
            p[int(line_content[0])] = [literal_eval(edge) for edge in line_content[1:]]
    source_vertex = next(iter(p.keys()))


print("Vertex 1's paths:", p[1])
print("1st value for vertex 1:", p[1][0])
print("1st neighbour of vertex 1:",p[1][0][0])
print("Distance of 1st neighbour of vertex 1:",p[1][0][1])


X = [1]
Y = [1]
A = {}
A[1] = 0
for i in range(2,201):
    A[i] = 100000000
    Y.append(i)


while X != Y:
    b = {}
    for eachvertex in X:
        b2 = 0
        for eachneighbour in p[eachvertex]:
            if eachneighbour[0] not in X:
                b2 = A[eachvertex]+eachneighbour[1]
                b[eachneighbour[0]] = b2
    vertex_to_be_added = min(b, key = b.get)
    X.append(vertex_to_be_added)
    A[vertex_to_be_added] = min(b.values())
    print("Vertex added :",vertex_to_be_added, "and distance :",min(b.values()))
    X.sort()
```

The data source can be found here :
[LinkToData](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_dcf1d02570e57d23ab526b1e33ba6f12_dijkstraData.txt?Expires=1656979200&Signature=jDtzBLV8iI%7EUD6soIHVD2PPZwLD3tcJwuSTS3ZPepSVvyrIuTM5VHstUOqosqy8pYJk%7EDMDUBfZfuISMJrgpiKuK63qda1%7EypGQVdv2cFIp8YHeg-tVjPI5C5rJm%7E4bA7JtKOu3boIwQ03FlVB17EojSDJ2tPpArMcpA-Yp6Et0_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

It works for the first iteration of the while loop, but after that the distances calculated for subsequent nodes/vertices added are not the shortest distance. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: `b` records the last arc to each node not yet in the tree, not the best. Thus the heap selection misfires.

Comment: I should do a comparison between b2 and previous arcs and assign the lowest one to b ?

Comment: Unless you have a dense graph, I would switch to a binary heap, one heap item per edge.

Comment: @user17420392, data link is unavailable. Access is denied.

Comment: X says to you which vertices you've already visited. Then you have this "not in X" thing. That's not right, because the fact you visited vertice doesnt mean it is the shortest path. You always need to check if you found the shortest one. Also it's guranteed to find the shortest paths in number of vertices iterations. So you dont have to track X and Y stuff. Take a look at some implementions on the internet.